# how to get value without iterating the List<Map>

Tags: java, spring, collections, spring-jdbc

I have `List<Map<String, Object>>`, the values are coming from database and I want to take the specified key related value without iterating..

```
List<Map<String, Object>> leastLevel = Dao.getValues();
```

the values are like below

```
leastLevel = [{LEVEL=level 1, R_ID=105, ID=1}]
```

Then I want to get R_ID directly without iterating. How can I get it.

Comment: The list is always 1 sized?

Comment: Yes the list is always 1 sized

Comment: Then don't use a list .... `Map<String, Object> leastLevel = Dao.getValues().get(0);`

Comment: Don't forget to check that really does have a size of 1. Better fail fast when that breaks than letting silent bugs go unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the element R_ID as follow:

```
leastLevel.get(0).get("R_ID");
```

That is possible because you know that the list is always 1 sized (as per your comment).

Comment: @AxelH You are right, but this is not related to the question. Additionally it is possible that this data comes from an external resource that can't be changed

Comment: "Not related to the question", the question is "how to read a list of size one without iterating", seems legit to tell that the list is not necessary in that case. `Dao.getValues().get(0)` would have more sense, if OP know the list is fixed, it is during the extraction, not anytime later. Just saying.